# How can I get winner-mode to not modify my keybindings?

Tags: key-bindings

I am trying to bind `C-c u` and `C-c r` to winner-mode's undo and redo in my `~/.emacs`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c u") 'winner-undo)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c r") 'winner-redo)
```

However, this doesn't work without `(winner-mode 1)`, which sets up some keybindings. And I don't want any of winner-mode's default keybindings. How can I make my `winner-undo` and `winner-redo` work without binding any other keys, preferably without installing other packages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about `(setq winner-dont-bind-my-keys t)`?  The doc-string for that variable states "*Non-nil means do not bind keys in Winner mode.*"

Comment: Works perfectly. Used it just above `(winner-mode 1)`.

Comment: I found this answer with:  `M-x find-library RET winner RET` and i-searching for mode-map, which is a common naming convention for key-binding maps.  In this case, it brought me to the `winner-mode-map` definition and I saw the variable `winner-dont-bind-my-keys`, and then I just went to the doc-string for that variable.  If the library had been loaded beforehand, I could have typed `M-x describe-variable` or `M-x find-variable` to inspect the doc-string.  If there was no such animal, then we could have unbound each key-binding that was undesired, or set the `winner-mode-map` to `nil`; or....